# SimpleCart(js) Select Option Issues

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am implementing my simpleCart items and am unable to transfer the size selection to the cart section in my HTML or through to PayPal. All other options work perfect, except for size??? I'm stumped, thank you in advance for any solutions or help.
Enjoy your day.

MY html:

```
<div id="myLB2"><h11>DNA</h11>
<div class="simpleCart_shelfItem">
<a class="item_add" href="javascript:;"><img src="./img/LB/dna2.jpg" width="250" height="280"></a>
<h14><select class="item_size">
<option value="xs">xs </option>
<option value="sm">sm </option>
<option value="md">md </option>
<option value="LG">LG </option>
<option value="XL">XL </option>
<option value="2X">2X </option>
<option value="3X">3X </option>
</select></h14>
<h15><span class="item_name">DNA</span><br/>
<span class="item_quantity"> 3 </span><br/>
<span class="item_price">$42.78</span></h15>
</div>

</div>
<div id="Storetotal">
<h12>Store</h12>

<h10>

<div>TOTAL<br/>
<span class="simpleCart_grandTotal"></span>
<a href="javascript:;" class="simpleCart_checkout">Checkout</a>
<span class="simpleCart_items"></span>

</div><br/>
</h10>  
</div>`
```

MY css:

```
h10{    
color: #1fbaf4;
font-family: Questrial ,Arial ,sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
opacity:.35;}

h11{    
color: #000000;
font-family: Questrial ,Arial ,sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
opacity:.9;}

h12{    
color: #1fbaf4;
position:fixed;
font-family: Questrial ,Arial ,sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
opacity:.35;
right:12em;}

h14{    
color: #1fbaf4;
opacity:.18;
font: 12px; 
font-family: Questrial ,Arial ,sans-serif;
letter-spacing:-.1em;
position:absolute;
top:1.5em;
left:.1em;}

h15{    
color: #1fbaf4;
font-family: Questrial ,Arial ,sans-serif;
opacity:0;
font: 12px;
letter-spacing:-.12em;
position:absolute;
top:3.6em;
left:.1em;}
```

simpleCart:

```
// default options
settings = {
checkout    : { type: "PayPal", email: "yoursite.com" },
currency    : "USD",
language    : "english-us",
cartStyle   : "div",


cartColumns : [
{ attr: "size", label: true },
{ attr: "name", label: false },
{ attr: "quantity", label: false },
{ attr: "price", label: "SubTotal", view: 'currency' },
{ view: "decrement", label: false },
{ view: "increment", label: false },
{ view: "remove", text: "Remove", label: false }
],
excludeFromCheckout : ['thumb'],
shippingFlatRate    : 0,
shippingQuantityRate    : 12.79,
shippingTotalRate   : 0,
shippingCustom      : null,
taxRate         : 0.064,
taxShipping     : false,
data    : {}
},
```

Comment: Shouldn't this { view: "size", label: true } be { attr: "size", label: true }

Comment: yes @Todd Moses , I apologize for the mistype. I'll revert it back to my original code. I copied and pasted a version where I changed the two. Neither works properly. thanks for pointing that out.